# Apache solr indexing using php curl (curl_error:Protocol "http not supported or disabled in libcurl)

Tags: apache, curl, solr

I am indexing a pdf file using this php script. The curl give me an error

> curl_error:Protocol "http not supported or disabled in libcurl

Here is my code please help me in this error, I am also searching for the error on the google i will respond to the post if I found the solution. Thanks in advance.

```
$result=move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
     if ($result == 1) echo "<p>Upload done .</p>";
        $options = getopt("f:");
        $infile = $options['f'];

        $url = "\"http://localhost:8983/solr/update/";
        $post_string = file_get_contents("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);

        $header = array("Content-type:text/xml; charset=utf-8");

        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);

        $data = curl_exec($ch);

        if (curl_errno($ch)) {
           print "curl_error:" . curl_error($ch);
        } else {
           curl_close($ch);
           print "curl exited okay\n";
           echo "Data returned...\n";
           echo "------------------------------------\n";
           echo $data;
           echo "------------------------------------\n";
        }
```

Comment: Thanks you are great.. it posted the data but i am stuck on this error HTTP ERROR 400 Problem accessing /solr/update. Reason: Unexpected character 'h' (code 104) in prolog; expected '<' at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,1] –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think...remove \"

```
$url = "http://localhost:8983/solr/update/";
       ^
```

Comment: $url value correct?  Please try to set to the address bar of your browser.

Comment: Thanks you are great.. it posted the data but i am stuck on this error
HTTP ERROR 400

Problem accessing /solr/update. Reason:

    Unexpected character 'h' (code 104) in prolog; expected '<'
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,1]

Comment: i think my file .txt that I am uploading contains the string hello world its is giving an error from the post string.